# Simple Logic in Left outer join Query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I Have two Tables  tblSiteVisits and tblConformedList and Colums as Below

**tblSiteVisits**

```
   Name   |   EmailAddress
```

**tblConformedList**

```
   Name   |   EmailAddress  |  ContactNo  |  Location    |   Conform_Status
```

The First Table Contains Name and EmailAddress of all those who have SiteVisits

Now in the Second table Conform_Status will be set either to 1 or 0 based on the client availability at point of time for site visit.

If not I will fill the ContactNo and Location and just update the table with Conform_Status = 0.

Now what i want is I want to take the Name and EmailAddress of people from table tblSiteVisits and  tblConformedList by relating the EmailAddress in join and the rows in tblConformedList whose  Conform_Status is 0.

That is List of people who have given ContactNo and Location for update but not given the Conform_Status.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, if you *only* need the rows where `Conform_Status` is 0, you don't need a `LEFT JOIN`, you need an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT v.* 
FROM tblSiteVisits v 
JOIN tblConformedList c 
ON v.EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress 
WHERE c.Conform_Status=0
```

Because the `c.Conform_Status=0` will filter out all rows where it is not 0, including the rows with NULL, rows in `tblSiteVisits` that have no correspondent row in `tblConformedList` will be filtered anyway - hence just use an `INNER JOIN`.

If you want an entry for all rows, then you can left-join, put the where-clause in the on-clause or add a `OR Conform_Status IS NULL` in your where clause.

```
SELECT v.* 
FROM tblSiteVisits v 
LEFT JOIN tblConformedList c 
ON v.EmailAddress = c.EmailAddress 
AND c.Conform_Status=0
```

This will display each row in `tblSiteVisits`, and if possible, the data for `tblConformedList`, but only when `Conform_Status` is actually 0.

Comment: Inner join wont work since intially the tblConformedList will be empty. Rows will be inserted into tblConformedList  once the site visit is conformed over telephone with Conform_Status 1 or 0

Comment: If initially tblconformedList will be empty, the `LEFT JOIN WHERE conformed=0` won't work either, since conformed can't be 0 where there are no rows. You want `conformed=0` in the ON, or `conformed=0 OR conformed IS NULL`. I edited my answer: the second query should indeed be a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

May be it helps you.

```
 select t1.* from tblSiteVisits t1 inner join tblConformedList t2 on  
 t1.EmailAddress=t2.EmailAddress where t2.Conform_Status=0
```

Try it and share your feedback.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. The above query does not works I don't know why I tried and that's y i posted this